# An error occurred, "The application has encountered an error 403" in Elavon Converge payment API call

Tags: html, api, godaddy

I am working on an HTML MVC website. Everything works fine on my local computer, but I am getting an error as soon as it's deployed on a hosting shared server (GoDaddy) while calling the converge API post to receive token:

```
Error:The application has encountered an error 403
```